# Play 2.4 Ebean pagination issue

Tags: java, sql-server, playframework, ebean, playframework-2.4

I want to use pagination in my application. Here is simple example:

```
public static List<MyClass> getPage(int page, int size) {
    PagedList<MyClass> findPagedList = Ebean.find(MyClass.class).findPagedList(page,size);
    return findPagedList.getList();
}
```

When I ask for the first page, I got my result with no problem but when I ask second page (page=1, size=10 for example) I got following error

> [PersistenceException: Query threw SQLException:Windowed functions do not support constants as ORDER BY clause expressions.

I'm using MsSQL ad a DB server. How can I fix it?

Thanks

PS here the raw SQL

```
select * 
from ( 
    select top 30
        row_number() over (order by null) as rn,
        t0.ID c0, t0.update_date c1, t0.create_date c2,
        t0.code c3, t0.is_fulfilled c4, t0.fulfill_date c5,
        t0.fulfill_request_id c6, t0.app_id c7,
        t0.access_code_header_id c8, t0.product_id c9
    from access_code_details t0
) as limitresult where  rn > 20 and  rn <= 30
```

My DB configurations:

```
db.default.url="jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:3333;databaseName=MyDB"
db.default.user=sa
db.default.password="******"
db.default.driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
ebean.default.databasePlatform=com.avaje.ebean.config.dbplatform.MsSqlServer2005Platform
ebean.default="model.*"
```

Comment: Catch actual SQL code  which is sent to DB and post here.

Comment: I've updated the question. Added SQL. It seems there is a real issue with SQL syntax. I got same error when I run in in SQL client. So should I change this syntax somehow?

Thanks

Comment: Great paging, TOP 30, no ORDER BY, row_number ordered by NULL. Can you change **SQL Dialect** for your ORM or sth like this?

Comment: Check persistence.xml and set dialect for MS SQL like `org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect` or higher if available.

Comment: lad2025, the closest configuration for dielect in ebean is ebean.default.databasePlatform=com.avaje.ebean.config.dbplatform.MsSqlServer2005Platform
which has no effect
I dont have persistence.xml since I'm not using hibernate

Comment: As you see your ORM gives incorrect syntax, so maybe you should ask authors of this framework or you configured it incorrectly.

Comment: Can you list the database configuration in your application.conf?

Comment: @joe776 , thanks for your answer. I've updated the post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I got it. When using pagination, must explicitly define order column in query.

```
Ebean.find(MyClass.class).order("id").findPagedList(page,size);
```

however the error message is completely messed up my mind.

Comment: is the static Ebean.find thread safe?? been looking for documentation but its not clear for me.

Answer (score 3):

Another way using `setFirstRow()` and `setMaxRows()`

```
Model.find.where().setFirstRow(offset).setMaxRows(limit).findList();
```

[Docs](https://ebean-orm.github.io/apidoc/10/io/ebean/ExpressionList.html#setFirstRow-int-)